# Postgres query where time within x seconds for given column values

Tags: postgresql

My table looks something like this (the `transfer_date` column is `bigint`):

```
 sensor_id │     transfer_date
═══════════╪════════════════════════
 1         │ 1600100000
 1         │ 1600200001
 1         │ 1600300010
 2         │ 1600100001
 2         │ 1600200010
 2         │ 1600300008
```

I need to find `transfer_date` for given pair of `sensor_id` where `transfer date`
is within `x` seconds of each other. Looking at table above if `x` is set to 3 the
query would return:

```
      transfer_date
 ═══════════════════════
  1600100000
  1600300010
```

Because only on those times both sensors transmitted within 3 seconds of each other.

I'm wondering if this is possible with nicely crafted SQL query or at least something close I can process quickly in code.

**EDIT 1:**

[@jonathan-jacobson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5524100/jonathan-jacobson) posted something very close to what I need (still need to test it on full data set) but his query needed some changes:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT sensor_id sid, transfer_date td
         , lag(sensor_id) OVER (ORDER BY transfer_date) prev_sid
         , lag(transfer_date) OVER (ORDER BY transfer_date) prev_td
    FROM sounds_tmp
    WHERE sensor_id IN ('1','2')
    ORDER BY transfer_date
)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE sid <> prev_sid AND td-prev_td <= interval '3 seconds';
```

**EDIT 2**

Finally I have used query which looks like this:

```
SELECT s1.sensor_id,
       s1.transfer_date,
       s2.sensor_id,
       s2.transfer_date
FROM sounds s1
         INNER JOIN sounds s2 ON (s1.sensor_id <> s2.sensor_id)
WHERE s1.sensor_id = 'abc123'
  AND s2.sensor_id = 'abc124'
  AND abs(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (s1.transfer_date - s2.transfer_date))) <= 3
  AND s1.transfer_date >= '2020-06-01T00:00:00+02:00'
  AND s1.transfer_date <= '2020-07-01T00:00:00+02:00'
```

Comment: `1600100000` is not a value that would appear in a `timestamptz` column - that looks like an `int` or `bigint`

Comment: Values in `transfer_date` are presented as a timestamp.

Comment: I don't understand. `1600100000` is not a [timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

Comment: 1600100000 = 14/09/2020 @ 4:13pm (UTC)

Comment: Your example response only includes the earliest timestamp of the pair of rows. What should the behavior be if there are >2 rows within 3 seconds - it still outputs only the earliest row? If so, what should the behavior be in the case of overlapping intervals? If your timestamps were 11, 14, 16, the output could reasonably be [11, 16], or just [14]. What is the intent?

Comment: I guess that is an edge case that can be handled in code. Ideally i shuld return all possible matches. @jonathan-jacobson posted something that is close to what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions such as `lag()` in order to access values from neighboring rows.

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT sensor_id sid, transfer_date td
         , lag(sensor_id) OVER (ORDER BY transfer_date) prev_sid
         , lag(transfer_date) OVER (ORDER BY transfer_date) prev_td
    FROM tab
    WHERE sensor_id IN (1,2)
    ORDER BY transfer_date
)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE sid <> prev_sid AND td-prev_td <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am following correctly, you can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        lead(transfer_date) over(partition by sensor_id order by transfer_date) lead_transfer_date,
        lag(transfer_date)  over(partition by sensor_id order by transfer_date) lag_transfer_date
    from mytable t
) t
where transfer_date <= lag_transfer_date  + interval '3 second'
   or transfer_date >= lead_transfer_date - interval '3 second'
```

Basically this brings all rows whose timestamp is less than 3 seconds away from the preceding or following timestamp.